# MVC Controller to Controller data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way in MVC to pass information from one controller to another? I have a character model that looks like this:

```
 public class Character
    {
        [Key]
        public string CharacterID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Str { get; set; }
        public int Con { get; set; }
        public int Dex { get; set; }
        public int Int { get; set; }
        public int Wis { get; set; }
        public int Cha { get; set; }
        public int BaseAttack { get; set; }
    }
```

And a separate weapon model like this:

```
 public class Weapons
    {
        [Key]
        public string WeaponID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string CharacterID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Range { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public int Crit { get; set; }
        public int CritMultiplier { get; set; }
        public string Hands { get; set; }
        public string Distance { get; set; }
    }
```

To create a weapon, you first need to create a character which assigned an ID, and I want to be able to pass that ID into the create method of my weapon controller. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TempData for this purpose. TempData stores data only between two requests. When you set the TempData the next request that is initiated can retrieve value from the TempData and it will be erased for any consequent requests.

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult CreateCharacter() 
{

  // creates charaeters here and sets the tempdata
  TempData['CharacterId'] = 50; 

  return RedirectToAction('CreateWeapon');
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateWeapon() 
{
  var weaponModel = new WeaponModel() { CharacterId = (int)TempData['CharacterId'] };
  return View(weaponModel);
}
```

and in your view simply have a hidden for the CharacterId, so it will be persisted if you your post fails validation or if you need to re-display the view.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(e => e.CharacterId);
```

Again this is just one approach, only if you you don't want to pass the CharacterId in the url.

You can also achive this just by passing it in the url:

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult CreateCharacter() 
{

  // creates charaeters here and sets the tempdata

  return RedirectToAction('CreateWeapon', new { characterId = 50 });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateWeapon(int characterId) 
{
  var weaponModel = new WeaponModel() { CharacterId = characterId };
  return View(weaponModel);
}
```

Comment: Don't use TempData for this.  TempData gets erased after the first time its accessed.  So what happens if the user refreshes the page?  The data in TempData is gone.

Comment: By the time it is erased you will already have the ID in your model.

Comment: My action comes from a view, so this line of code is in my character index view
     @Html.ActionLink("Create Weapon", "Create", "Weapons") 

is it possible to set the temp data there or do I have to do it in a controller method first?

Comment: Unlikely, since the user has to first fill out a form before it gets saved to the model. If they press F5 before they save, the id is gone.  Otherwise, you would save it to the model BEFORE you redirect.

Comment: @NerdyWizard you can use the same parameters I gave for `RedirectToAction()` in my answer and apply them to `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: Regarding your update... If you refresh the page, characterId will be null with TempData.

Comment: The page will be cached and does not need to be re-retrieved from he server if you just press F5, of course if there is no cache attribute. Also  if there are validation errors you just store it in a hidden field. But I agree if you can put as route parameter as well.

Comment: The page may or may not be returned from cache... That's a client-side thing and may or may not be honored. maybe they pressed Ctrl-F5... maybe they cleared their cache because an image didn't load correctly... the point being, it's not a reliable way to do things.  If the page is re-rendered, the value is gone and the app will crash, or at best have no idea what id to work with because it's simply gone.  TempData should only be used for short lived data that you don't care if it sticks around, like information messages (ie "Record Updated" or something).

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you don't want the id in the url and I had it a couple of times as a requirement.

Comment: And that's fine, but TempData is NEVER the way to do it, and you should not be recommending it as the way to do it.  You should use PRG instead.

Comment: Why not it is still an option, with its pitfalls of course but still an option.

Comment: It's an option in the same way that not catching exceptions is an option... It's shoddy programming and crashing code waiting to happen, simply by the user doing something they should be able to do.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree on that one... Nothing wrong with TempData if you know how you to use it, never crashed my code with null exception or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to pass the character id to the create weapon action via routing, either as a route token that forms part of the path or via the query string. Be sure to check that the weapon can logically be associated with the character to whom the id corresponds.

You could also pass the id using `TempData` or `Session`, but considering both by default will take up memory on the web server, the simple option is to use the routing. In addition, unless you call `TempData.Keep("key")` after accessing `TempData`, the value will be removed from `TempData` after the first access, potentially causing issues if the user refreshes the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RedirectToAction()`, though as titled this will cause browser redirection.

```
return RedirectToAction("CreateWeapon", "Weapon", new { id = yourid });
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("CreateWeapon", "Create", new { id = yourid })
```

Edit: Your plain object property names and your action method variables need to match, to do this.